# Python: A list of lists, return element(s) that exist in all "sub-lists"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of lists.  I need to find and return the element that exists in all of the "sub-lists" in my larger list.

```
list_of_lists = [["superman", "batman", "spiderman"], ["aquaman", "superman"]]
```

How would I return "superman" from the list_of_lists.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any knowledge of the contents of the list, so I wouldn't be able to check explicitly for "superman".

Comment: I had answered, but found an exact duplicate (much better answered!) afterwards. You could do: `print(set.intersection(*map(set, list_of_lists)))`

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
s = set(itertools.chain(*list_of_lists))
for lst in list_of_lists:
    s &= set(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
>>> set.intersection(*map(set, list_of_lists))
set(['superman'])
```

Or, if you only have Python < 2.7:

```
>>> reduce(lambda s1, s2: s1 & s2, map(set, list_of_lists))
set(['superman'])
```